# Eureka set display values

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

i'm trying to set the display value of a MultipleSelectorRow. However when i try to compile below i keep getting an error with `return t.name` where it say `Value of type Set<Ladder> has no member name`. The `let ranks = Array(game.ranks)` is of type `Array<Ladder>`. What am i doing wrong in order to show the name from Ladder object?

```
        <<< MultipleSelectorRow<Ladder>("Rank") {
            $0.hidden = Condition.predicate(NSPredicate(format: "$Game == nil"))
            $0.title = $0.tag


            }.cellUpdate { cell, row in

                let formvalues = self.form.values()
                let game = formvalues["Game"] as! Game
                let ranks = Array(game.ranks)
                row.options = ranks
                row.displayValueFor = {
                    if let t = $0 {
                        return t.name

                    }
                    return nil
                }


                cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 16)

                cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
                cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
                cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

        }
```

Ladder class

```
class Ladder: Object, Mappable{

    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["_id"]
        name <- map["name"]


    }

    override var description: String {

        return "\(self.name)"
    }



}
```

Comment: can you share your `Ladder` class?

Comment: i've shared it now

Comment: did you figure out a how to do this ? TIA